# merging lists within lists via time stamp

Tags: list, r, merge, timestamp, dataframe

I´ve asked for this on R-help one week ago, no answer until now... I´ve got multiple data.frames of gps- and temperature-data within a list. One data.frame looks like:

GPS:

```
       date     time     x.lat     x.lon   
1      22.05.11 13:50:37 53.57908 10.034599 
2      22.05.11 13:50:38 53.57906 10.034633
```

temp:

```
        date     time     temp
1      22.05.11 13:50:38 21.6120
2      22.05.11 13:50:39 21.6070
```

So I have two lists, one with multiple gps-data.frames and one with multiple temp-dataframes. I used lapply to manipulate both lists, but can´t merge temp and gps to one big list, containing all data.frames, for only time-stamps which exists in both list, like for the above example only 13:50:38 exists in both:

GPS+temp:

```
       date     time    x.lat     x.lon     temp
1      22.05.11 13:50:38 53.57906 10.034633 21.6070
```

For the single data-frames that worked just fine with:

```
both <- merge(gps,temp)
```

For the two lists of data.frames I first tried an lapply over both lists...something like

```
both <- lapply(temp, gps, function(x){x <- merge(x);x})
```

Then I tried it with

```
both <- merge.list(gps,temp)
```

but this doesn´t work either. It just transfers the first list "gps" to both

Comment: Your terminology is either confused or confusing. You say you "have two lists, one with multiple gps-data.frames and one with multiple temp-dataframes" but you do not give an example of such a structure. "GPS" and "temp" do not display like "lists of dataframes" would. Do you really have lists whose elements are dataframes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Map`:

```
> Map(merge, GPS, temp)
[[1]]
      date     time    x.lat    x.lon   temp
1 22.05.11 13:50:38 53.57906 10.03463 21.612
```

or just call `mapply` like `Map` does:

```
> mapply(merge, GPS, temp, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
[[1]]
      date     time    x.lat    x.lon   temp
1 22.05.11 13:50:38 53.57906 10.03463 21.612
```

Comment: Thanks,that worked. Another solution posted by Joshua Wiley-2 in R-Help is:
lapply(seq_along(GPS), function(i) {
  merge(GPS[[i]], temp[[i]])
})